# Script inside update panel is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using some scripts in my .aspx pages. It was working before I put update panel in these pages. I need both things, update panel and scripts. How to enable these scripts inside the update panel in asp.net? I am using c# and asp.net 4.5 framework.
The scripts that I used in the pages are:

  1.

> Response.Write("alert('Successfully Updated')");

2.

```
string url = "./Quick.aspx";
   string cmd = "window.open('" + url + "', '_blank', 'height=600,width=600,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,titlebar=no' );";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "newWindow", cmd, true);
   }
```

These codes are used in the .aspx.cs pages.

Any idea about this issue to solve?

Thanks....

Comment: Does the second script not work when using update panels? It should

Comment: In order to fix the first script, you cannot use Response.Write (as you have identified). The solution is to use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript as follows: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript( this, this.GetType(), "SuccessAlert", "alert('Successfully Updated');", true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Is a simply way.

//Common.Response.Write("<Script>alert('Successfully Updated')</Script>");

```
    string url = "Quick.aspx";
    string cmd = "alert('Successfully Updated');window.open('" + url + "', '_blank', 'height=600,width=600,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,titlebar=no' );";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "newWindow", cmd, true);
```

Comment: you answer your question within 1 minute? then why you ask it?

Answer (score 0):

Place the Javascript outside the UpdatePanel, it will work...

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the first script (1), you cannot use Response.Write as this code could be executed in an async postback, and this is what you have experienced.
The solution is to use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript as follows:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                        this,
                        this.GetType(),
                        "SuccessAlert",
                        "alert('Successfully Updated');",
                        true);
```

You can find some more information about the RegisterStartupScript here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558(v=vs.110).aspx